# How to derive specific elements from an attribute of a database and connect them to the primary key?

Tags: python, mysql, database

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `user_id` int NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `hobby` varchar(50) #optional, hobby is always written in hashtags 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `user` (`user_id`, `name`, `hobby`)
('148723', 'max', 'random text #football'),
('578294', 'john', 'random text2'),
...
```

I want to create a table with only the ID and the hobby like so:

```
('148723', '#football')
...
```

Is there any way to do this in MySQL or do I have to use Python? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create a new table es.`user_and_hobby`

```
CREATE TABLE `user_and_hobby` (
  `user_id` int NOT NULL,
  `hobby` varchar(50) 
);
```

then import data from another table es. `user`:

```
INSERT INTO `user_and_hobby` (`user_id`, `hobby`)
    SELECT user_id, concat('#',SUBSTRING_INDEX(hobby, "#", -1))
    FROM user
    WHERE hobby LIKE "%#%"
```

For more example about insert+select you can find [here](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-insert-into-select/).

- `CONCAT` add `#` before string ([documentation](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat-function.php)).
- `SUBSTRING_INDEX` select hashtag word without # ([documentation](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php)).
- `LIKE` remove hobby without hashtag

I suppose you have only one hashtag for hobby, if this is not the case, modify the question by entering all possible cases

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! However, in the new table I only want to have the text written in the hashtag like this: ('148723', #football) and not the random text. And it's way too many rows to import it one at a time. Isn't there a possibility to derive all ID's and the corresponding #hobby? :/